# Python Multiple While True Loop, Looking for a Neat way???

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am looking for a neat way way to have multiple while loops.

I understand that you can have multiple nested while loops under each other to keep continuous flow.

In the below code the first while loop goes through and clicks on the soldiers, and the second while loop does the same, however in future while loops for different levels (Up to 35) the code will change, but will still need to be flowing.

I don't want to have 35 ***nested*** while loops, I am looking for a way to keep continuous flow through each level (while loop) as options change per level

```
 while True:  # loop because it because the Soldier is animated and displayed at the moment.
        soldier = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('soldier_1.png'), region=GAME_REGION, confidence=.5,
                                                 grayscale=True)
        continueButton = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('continue_button.png'), region=GAME_REGION,
                                                            confidence=.6, grayscale=True)

        if soldier != None:
            #soldierCount.append(soldier)
            x, y = soldier
            x, y = int(x), int(y)
            aim_mouse.thompsonAimer.handle_click(x, y)
        else:
            # Move Mouse to the Centre Screen
            centreScreen = int(screenWidth / 2 - 130), int(screenHeight / 2)
            x, y = centreScreen
            ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)
            #pass

            # Press the Continue Button If Avaliable
            if continueButton == None:
                continue
            else:
                pyautogui.click(continueButton, duration=0.25)
                logging.info('Clicked on Continue button.')


            """Level 2"""
            # Function for First and Second Level
            print(8 * "-", "Level 2", 8 * "-")

            while True:  # loop because it because the Soldier is animated and displayed at the moment.
                soldier = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('soldier_1.png'), region=GAME_REGION, confidence=.5,
                                                             grayscale=True)
                continueButton = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('continue_button.png'), region=GAME_REGION,
                                                        confidence=.6, grayscale=True)

                if soldier != None:
                    print("Soldier Located at:", soldier)
                    x, y = soldier
                    x, y = int(x), int(y)
                    aim_mouse.thompsonAimer.handle_click(x, y)
                else:
                    # Move Mouse to the Centre Screen
                    centreScreen = int(screenWidth / 2 - 130), int(screenHeight / 2)
                    x, y = centreScreen
                    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)

                    # Press the Continue Button If Avaliable
                    if continueButton == None:
                        continue
                    else:
                        pyautogui.click(continueButton, duration=0.25)
                        logging.info('Clicked on Continue button.')
```

Is there a way to break out of a while True loop, then recommence it again immediately after? Or is there a way better way to write this aka perhaps multiple indented while loop functions per level, or a class?

Or perhaps just a tonne of if then else statements for levels?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you find yourself repeating code like this, it's time to learn about functions. I don't even think its possible to nest loops 35 levels deep; IIRC it throws an error after 20 or so.

Comment: Recursion is the way, my friend.

Comment: As suggested, you need to look at functions and perhaps rethink some of your logic.  Base on the code shown, you have done nothing different in both the inner and outer loops except a simple print statement.  This would lead me to wonder exactly what it is your trying to achieve??

Comment: Agreed for this example both loops do the same, as explained in further while loops the code will change, aka change weaopns etc what I am after was continuous multiple while loops for each level. Without breaking the flow looks like I will have to research into functions.

Comment: You will not just have to look into functions, but also into event loops and managing levels in games.